# Haml::Util.html_safe ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

This error appeared today, and I have absolutely no clue about what caused it.

[image: better errors screenshot]

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-27 13:35:11 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered user_sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 3):
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/util.rb:89:in `html_safe'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:22:in `html_escape_with_haml_xss'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:445:in `block in build_attributes'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:428:in `build_attributes'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:503:in `prerender_tag'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:177:in `compile_tag'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:22:in `compile'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:22:in `block in compile'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:95:in `compile_root'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/compiler.rb:22:in `compile'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/engine.rb:66:in `initialize'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/template/plugin.rb:25:in `compile'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/template/plugin.rb:30:in `call'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:270:in `compile'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in compile!'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `compile!'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/krpec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  request_store (1.0.6) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/krpec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/krpec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/krpec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

No matter what path I'm trying, it always ends up with this ArgumentError. The only different thing is when I'm trying to access a page which is protected (before_action filter for requiring user to be logged in), there is different line higlighted on better errors screen: `redirect_to signin_path` from this method:

```
def require_user
    unless current_user
        store_location
        flash[:warning] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
        redirect_to signin_path
        return false
    end
end
```

Here is result of `bundle list`:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.2)
  * actionpack (4.1.2)
  * actionview (4.1.2)
  * activemodel (4.1.2)
  * activerecord (4.1.2)
  * activesupport (4.1.2)
  * ancestry (2.1.0)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * authlogic (3.4.2)
  * bcrypt (3.1.7)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
  * better_errors (1.1.0)
  * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  * bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.3.0.2)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
  * bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.6.2)
  * cancancan (1.8.0)
  * capybara (2.3.0)
  * celluloid (0.15.2)
  * chartkick (1.2.4)
  * childprocess (0.3.6)
  * coderay (1.1.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * database_cleaner (1.2.0)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.2)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * enumerize (0.8.0)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.2.1)
  * factory_girl (4.4.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
  * faker (1.1.2)
  * ffi (1.9.3)
  * ffi-compiler (0.1.3)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * guard (2.6.1)
  * guard-rspec (4.2.10)
  * guard-spork (1.5.1)
  * haml (4.0.5)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * jbuilder (1.0.2)
  * jquery-rails (3.0.4)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * listen (2.7.9)
  * lumberjack (1.0.9)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * mini_portile (0.6.0)
  * minitest (5.3.5)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
  * mysql2 (0.3.16)
  * nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
  * nyan-cat-formatter (0.9.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.5)
  * pry (0.10.0)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.1.2)
  * railties (4.1.2)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.5)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * request_store (1.0.6)
  * rspec (3.0.0)
  * rspec-core (3.0.2)
  * rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
  * rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
  * rspec-rails (3.0.1)
  * rspec-support (3.0.2)
  * rubyzip (0.9.9)
  * sass (3.2.13)
  * sass-rails (4.0.2)
  * scrypt (1.2.1)
  * sdoc (0.3.20)
  * selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
  * slop (3.5.0)
  * spork (1.0.0rc4)
  * spork-rails (4.0.0)
  * sprockets (2.11.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.4)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timers (1.1.0)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * turbolinks (1.1.1)
  * tzinfo (1.2.1)
  * uglifier (2.1.1)
  * websocket (1.0.7)
  * will_paginate (3.0.5)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**UPDATE:** here is `new.html.haml`

```
- provide(:title, t('views.user_session.title'))
.row.sign-in
    .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
        .well.well-sm
            = form_for(:user_session, url: user_sessions_path, html: { class: "form-signin" }) do |f|
                %h2.text-center.form-signin-heading= t('views.user_session.heading')
                = f.email_field :email, placeholder: t('activerecord.attributes.user_session.email'), class: "form-control"
                = f.password_field :password, placeholder: t('activerecord.attributes.user_session.password'), class: "form-control"
                = f.submit t('views.user_session.sign_in_button'), class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: What does `user_sessions/new.html.haml` look like?

Comment: Don't see anything there, maybe it's in layouts/application

Comment: @Iceman [application.html.haml](http://pastebin.com/wStpFUdK)

Comment: I would try to debug it temporarly modifing the HAML file in this way: `def html_safe(text); p text, text.method(:html_safe).source_location; ... end`

Comment: Rails 4.1.2 has only just been released, do you get this error in 4.1.1?

Comment: @matt Yeah, I've actually updated to 4.1.2 today after this error occured, no difference between 4.1.1 and 4.1.2

Comment: @mdesantis I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion correctly.. I tried to update haml/util.rb with provided code, but got no improvement. When on better-errors screen, I tried this in live console: `>> text.method(:html_safe)
=> #<Method: String#html_safe>
>> text.method(:html_safe).source_location
=> ["/Users/krpec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/shellwords.rb", 219]
>>`

Comment: My code is in order to find where is defined the method which raises the issue. It's quite weird to me that the method `html_safe` is defined inside `shellwords.rb` file; are you sure?

Comment: @mdesantis That's what the console told me.. [Here](http://pastebin.com/A4viCjVi) is dump of the file. As you'll see, there are those methods (all of them are in fact empty). `cashpooling_structure` is one of the models in my application. I'd say that those definitions should not be there, am I right? It's definitely not something I wrote to the file.

Comment: Definitely not! [This](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_1/lib/shellwords.rb) is the original `shellwords.rb` file; you can download it and replace it with yours, which is clearly broken. Maybe you modifed that file by error? And remember to restore the HAML source file removing the debug lines

Comment: @mdesantis I've got it working now, just commented out those empty html_safe. But I'll download the file you linked, thanks! I'm really sure I did not modify this file, as it's not directly in my project directory. HAML source file is in its original state, and it works! So thanks all of you for help!! :)